# How to count the total number of relations in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying the following query,

`start n=node(*) match (n)-[r]->(m) return count(r)`

I am not sure if this query is fine.

Answer (score 5):

You should use this query : `MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(*)`

Cheers.

PS: The `start, match` query form should be only used for legacy index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to count the number of relationships :

```
MATCH ()-[r:NAME_OF_RELATIONSHIP]->() RETURN count(r)
```